# How to get url_helper to pass permalink instead of id in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, seo, url-routing, permalinks

I have the following route in my Rails3 project:

```
match "/blog/:permalink" => "posts#show", :as => :post
```

When I link to my post through a view as such:

```
<%= link_to @post.title, post_path(@post) %>
```

The id of the post is passed into the post_path helper (even though my route specifies the permalink is passed.

How do I force the post_path to send in the permalink instead of the id of the post?
I can explicitly call `post_path(@post.permalink)` but that seems dirty.

Am I missing something in my route?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a `to_param` method on the model that returns the string you want to use.

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def to_param
    permalink
  end
end
```

See [this page](http://www.seoonrails.com/to_param-for-better-looking-urls.html), [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/63-model-name-in-url), (and of course [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=rails+model+to_param)) for more info.

[Edit]

I don't think [Polymorphic URL Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html) are smart enough to handle what you want to do here. I think you have two options.

**1. Use a special named route and pass in the parameter similar to your question and Jits' answer.**

```
match "/blog/:permalink" => "posts#show", :as => :post
```

and link to it

```
<%= link_to @post.title, post_path(:permalink => @post.permalink) %>
```

**2. Create a new helper that generates the URL for you**

```
match "/blog/:permalink" => "posts#show", :as => :post_permalink
```

and a helper

```
def permalink_to(post)
  post_permalink_path(post.permalink)
end
```

and in your views

```
<%= link_to @post.title, permalink_to(@post) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this way any url_helper I call is going to use the permalink instead of the id for every request regardless of the path. I don't want to end up with something like `blog/my-post/edit` (that one should use the id). Therefore, I am looking for a specific way to alter only the `show` path. Thanks!comments may only be edited for 5 minutes(click on this box to dismiss)

Comment: @yuval: `post_path(@post.permalink)` when necessary then.

Comment: @yuval: Agreed, the polymorphic URL helpers aren't gonna cut it for you. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Should be :as => :post and :as => :post_permalink
(add a :)

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```
<%= link_to @post.title, post_path(:permalink => @post.permalink) %>
```

Rails should automatically construct the URL as per your routes (i.e. replacing `:permalink` accordingly).

Comment: Oh wait, I've just seen that you've tried something similar. Please ignore my answer. What exactly would you prefer to see/do?